# The discriminant of composite field of two non-linearly independent fields.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> [Proposition]
> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ over a number field $K$. Assume $f(x) \in \mathcal{O}_K[x]$ and is monic. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $K$, and suppose that $$ f(x) \equiv f_1(x)f_2(x) \cdots f_r(x) \hspace{3mm } \text{ mod } \mathfrak{p}$$
> with the $f_i$ distinct irreducible polynomials in $k[x]$ and $f_i$ of degree $n_i$, $k= \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified in the splitting field of $f$.

---

> [Proof] This is because that $\mathfrak{p}$ doesn't divide the discriminant of $f$.

---

[My question and try]

I don't understand this proof.

If $f$ is a minimal polynomial of a primitive element $\theta$ such that  $\mathcal{O}_L= \mathcal{O}_K[\theta]$, then we're done but this is not the case.

Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f$ and $\mathcal{O}_L$ be the ring of integer of $L$.

If $\mathfrak{p}$ doesn't divide the discriminant of  $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathcal{O}_K$ , then we're done.

However, is there the relation between the discriminant of  $\mathcal{O}_L/\mathcal{O}_K$ and the discriminant of $f$ ?

I know that if two field extensions $K_1/K$, $K_2/K$ are linearly independent, then $$disc{K_1K_2} \mid (disc{K_1})(disc{K_2}) $$ , so we can show the proposition by applying this property to the splitting fields of irreducible factors of $f$. (Furthermore, we don't know $K_i \cap K_j = K $)

Is it always possible to prove without these linearly independent conditions?

Thank you for your attention.